How can I write unit tests with a future timestamp?
I have an ICO program created using Anchor, and I want to test with a future timestamp. How can I write unit tests with a future timestamp?

You can use Solana Bankrun time travel to do this:
https://kevinheavey.github.io/solana-bankrun/tutorial/#time-travel
    const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    // Turn forward the clock for 11 minutes
    const currentClock = await client.getClock();
    context.setClock(
      new Clock(
        currentClock.slot,
        currentClock.epochStartTimestamp,
        currentClock.epoch,
        currentClock.leaderScheduleEpoch,
        BigInt(timestamp) + BigInt(60 * 11)
      )
    );

Here is an example:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-preset/blob/main/program/jesttests/energy-refill-time.test.ts
luzid.app supports similar features. Havent tried it yet though.

I like this summary at Ackee bootcamp
https://github.com/Ackee-Blockchain/Solana-Auditors-Bootcamp/tree/master/Lesson-2#testing-using-typescript-1

Wait for the amount of time you need to get over the threshold.

It's good to set short thresholds in your program for testing
Setup test validator to set shorter time for epoch length
https://github.com/marinade-finance/marinade-ts-sdk/blob/v5.0.6/Anchor.toml#L28



For example in our SDK tests, we wait to get the stake account activated
https://github.com/marinade-finance/marinade-ts-sdk/blob/v5.0.6/test/test-world.ts#L210

Use solana bankrun https://github.com/kevinheavey/solana-bankrun/ for testing where you can fast forward (or backwards) the time with warp_to_slot or warp_to_epoch or https://github.com/kevinheavey/solana-bankrun/blob/main/tests/clock-example/clock.test.ts#L28


i am not sure to understand where is the problem here ? Just get the current timestamp and add X seconds to it ?
